# How Can I call a dynamic index in function cshtml?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, asp.net-core

I have this function :

```
<script>
     function f(id){
        return $("#" + id).val();
     }
</script>
```

And this html's tag:

```
<input id=f(@payMethod) type="radio" value=" @method.Value" name="cartaCont" />
```

My id is buildered with a foreach that pass value to variable:

```
string payMethod = "payMethod";
payMethod += method.Text;
```

My question is: **Is correct Call this index in an other function in this way ??** :

```
function() {
     $('input[id ^= #PayMethod]').attr('checked', headerChecked);
}
```

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to write some html and javascript code, relating to each item of a list.

In this case, I often prefer to directly write html and related javascript for event binding and code customization.

I supposing that `method` is your razor variable in your foreach, and `methods` is the enumerable variable to loop, you may would write this code for html

```
@foreach(var method in methods)
{
 // this is C#, not javascript
 // replacing spaces to build right id code for html
 string payMethod = "payMethod" + method.Value.Replace(" ", ""); 
 <text>
  <input id="@payMethod" class="payMethodRadio" type="radio" value="@method.Value" name="cartaCont" />
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#@payMethod").on('change', function (e) {
    /* here if you want to write some javascript events for each item related to its html ID, for example change event */
   });
  });
  </script>
 </text>
}
```

But if you want to write some common jQuery code for this set of radio buttons, I' prefer to manage it with class selector rather than ID rules, as follow

```
function() {
     $('payMethodRadio')...
}
```

Hope this, help you for better code management.

Br
Andryx

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Onchange event to input.Here is a demo code:

```
@{var payMethod = 0;}
@foreach (var method in Model.Methods)
{
    <input id="@payMethod" type="radio" value=" @method.Value" name="cartaCont" onchange="Add(@payMethod)"/>
    payMethod++;
}
```

js:

```
function Add(id) {
            $('#'+id).attr('checked', headerChecked);
        }
```